# No Wayland after messing around with amdgpu-install for ROCM

Tags: steam, wayland, amdgpu, beta

**Hello fellow FOSS-lovers.**

I have been using my current Ubuntu install on my main desktop at home for gaming and some software development since a few version back. I have had wonderful performance and usability with my AMD Radeon 7900XT card both in gaming and all the desktop work that i do. Wayland has been active and i have been having awesome 3d acceleration present in all my workloads.

I have also been using **23.10** beta since that released a few days back without any big issues. That is until i hit a little snag when trying to utilize **ROCM** from **amdgpu-install** to run stable-diffusion. Around the same time i got an update to kernel **6.5.0-7**, i later restarted the computer and noticed that before my default mouse pointer showed up i got that weird X in its place for about a second. And then after loggign in 3d acceleration seemed very poor with windows "clipping" when moved around. I checked and realized i was running X11. I logged out and looked for the cogg to activate Wayland but it is nowhere to be found. Also, Steam refuses to start.

I assume i have somehow manged to break Wayland or some component, maybe related to my graphics driver. That is required to run Wayland, i know i am kind of begging for it running a beta and messing around with the amd driver packages. But it would still be very nice not having to reinstall my desktop to get back into action.

Does anywhere out there have any idea what could have happened? I have set `WaylandEnabled=true` in the gdm3 config but it has made no difference. And glxgears gives me about 4796 FPS so i guess the mesa drivers are alive and kicking. Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (*mantic*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *mantic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 12 October 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: You have probably moved on already, but I had a similar problem and for me it was that amdgpu install created a file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf which blacklisted the amdgpu kernel module. After commenting out the line in that file (and recreating initramfs ) Wayland worked again